# How to know iteration value of a loop controller in an if controller in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to execute multiple requests inside a loop controller. But few of them are required to be executed based on some conditions. So when its 2, 4th, 6th, 8th..20th transaction, I will require to execute first set of request.
But when its 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th transaction, I need to execute some other set.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reading [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller):

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named LC, then you can access the looping index through ${__jm__LC__idx}. Index starts at 0

Loop Controller exposes `__jm__Loop Controller__idx` variable which returns current iteration number (zero-based)

[image]

The change is available since [JMeter 4.0](http://$%7B__groovy(vars.get(%27__jm__Loop%20Controller__idx%27)%20+%201,)%7D)

So you should be able to get 2nd, 4th, etc. iteration in the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like `${__groovy(((vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int) +1) % 2 == 0,)}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I was using same function. But I was using it in wrong way. Thanks for providing the corrected one. Many Thanks :)